# Web iPad app to be downloaded / short cut added to home screen from page - is that possible?

Tags: ipad, web-applications, sencha-touch

I am developing a web iPad app using Sencha Touch framework.
As it is a JS and Html5 framework It allows me to use cashing and work offline. 
If I use the "+" button on iPad's Safari I can ad the icon/ shortcut to the home screen and make it behave as a native app (work without safari's address bar).

I was wandering would it be possible to create a button on the web page that would have the same functionality as the "+" button - so it allows users to add a web app shortcut to their ipad's home screens directly from the web page.

Is it possible? Can JS deal with it using apple's API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, but this isn't possible. (JavaScript has no access to any special Apple API's - merely some additional events for touch handlers, etc.)

If it was, you can imagine that it would be trivial for any web site to automate this process (fake the user pressing the in-page "add" button) and hence add itself to the user's home screen without their permission.

Comment: I thought that there might have been a way with an obligatory prompt/ question for user's permission, but I understand there could be to many security issues.

Comment: @Dkatstack Perhaps in the future, but there's currently no mechanism like that.